# Parse Cloud deleting objects from query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I can't figure out how to delete all the objects retrieved via a Parse Cloud job query. When I run this job, nothing from the database has been deleted.

Here's the troublesome snippet:

```
query.find({
    success: function(posts) {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts);
        status.success("success");
    },
    error: function(error) {
        status.error("Error finding posts " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
    },
});
```

I have also tried using a for-loop and calling .destroy() on each post, which doesn't work. I also tested changing attributes on each post using .set(), which also didn't work. However, I am easily able to use .get() to retrieve attributes. Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE: It was an authentication error.

```
useMasterKey: true
```

Adding this to destroyAll() as an option made it work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Javascript, but what is the syntax of adding the `useMasterKey: true` as an option to the `destroyAll()`?

Answer (score 5):

Try waiting for the destroy to complete before continuing.. something like:

```
query.find({
    success: function(posts) {
        Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts).then(function() {
            status.success("success");
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        status.error("Error finding posts " + error.code + ": " + error.message);
    },
});
```

Asynchronous JavaScript trips everyone up.

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. The log reads "Failed with: success/error was not called," which suggests that destroyAll() is not actually called?

Comment: Well, you said it was a job (not just a function.)  It's probably timing out after 15 seconds.

Comment: Check if *any* are being deleted?

Comment: It is a job. I thought that gave it 15 minutes before timing out? And nothing is being deleted.

Comment: How are you running it?  Do you have additional code after the query block?

Comment: No - there is nothing after this block

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I'm running it as a "Scheduled Job" on the Parse Cloud

Comment: Add additional logging... inside the success block before destroyAll.. log posts.. logs everywhere.

Comment: Just logged everything I could think of. It's executing the "success" block, but not destroyAll(). No query error is being called. Hm. Stumped.

Comment: "posts" has a length of 7, which indicates it exists and deleting shouldn't be an expensive operation

Comment: Found the solution. Thank you.